# Create one-to-many relationship sqlite ios

Tags: ios, xcode, sqlite, one-to-many

First of all I'm new at using `SQLite`.

I created my tables and linked them. However I can only create what seems to be a one-to-one relationship.

I want to have a double-headed arrow (like in this image: [image: desc]) to point on my table `PublicMedia` (I want my table Location to point on several of my other table `PublicMedia`).

How can I achieve that using `XCode` interface and not `SQLite` code ?

Comment: Xcode will only support creation of Core Data schemas, which will use sqlite as the database, however there is no support for creating sqlite schemas directly in Xcode.

Comment: So how can I create that double-headed arrow like in the link I posted ? The one that point on "Friend" or "Source"

Comment: Great. I searched but couldn't find the answer. Thanks exculuber :)